# I need to setup a continuous alert message when a user try to close the page

Tags: javascript, html, alert

Here I have a basic code which will create an alert message when the user tries to close the webpage.What I need is the user should get repeated alerts when he tries to close the page and also need automatic alerts based on the time frame once he tries to close the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return " page go"

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, do not even try to do that. Ever.

Comment: This is impossible with reason. Keeping users from leaving your page makes your website malware.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, doing this is stupid, but nonetheless:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    while(true){
        alert("X");
    }
}
</script>
```

Second, your goal is pointless, and impossible, as modern browsers have this lovely checkbox that appears after a few alerts.

[image: Prevent additional dialogs]

---

[image: Prevent additional dialogs]

Answer (score 0):

You can send up alerts before a user leaves your page like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uL4axrL4/)**

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```